# Different content in popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, popupwindow

I'm changing my old online quiz to a more interactive one where they can learn while answering the questions. I manage to create a popup and it goes to the next question when clicking the button in the popup. But i need help in displaying the certain content(popup with **congratulate words** when they answered a question **correctly**, and popup with **explanation** if they answered it **wrong**) please help me, thank you.

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <a href="#myPopupDialog" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade"
               class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline">Continue</a>


            <div data-role="popup" id="myPopupDialog">
                <div data-role="header">
                    <h1>Header Text</h1>
                </div>

                <div id="divNextButton" class="ui-content">
                    <h2>Content and explaination here</h2>
                    <button type="button" id="nexttab" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
                        Next question <span class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></span>
                    </button>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>








    $('#nexttab').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(function () {

            var toggleTab = $('.nav-tabs li').filter('.active').next('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]');
            toggleTab.tab('show');
            $('#questionNo').html(toggleTab.data('qno'));
            loadQuestion(toggleTab.data('qid'), toggleTab.data('jid'));
        }, 200);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below popup function i'm reusing in every project of mine.
I wrote it 2 years ago and still it's doing the job as excepted.

You should just pass your text to the popup function and that's it.
Let me know please if this one is help you.

```js
var popup = {
    inputCallback: null,
    isActive: false,
    hide: function () {
        $('.popup-container').animate({ "z-index": "-1", "opacity": "0" }, 200);
        popup.isActive = false;
        if (popup.inputCallback != null && popup.inputCallback != undefined)
            popup.inputCallback.focus();
    },
    show: function (title, text) {
        if (!popup.isActive) {
            popup.isActive = true;
            text = ((text != "") && (text != undefined)) ? text : "";
            $('.popup-description').html('<p>' + text + '</p>');
            title = title != "" && title != undefined ? title : "";
            $('.popup-title').html("<h1>" + title + "</h1>");
            $('.popup-container').css({ "z-index": "9999" });
            $('.popup-container').animate({ "opacity": "1" }, 1000);

            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.popup-wrapper').focus();
                $('.close-popup').focus();
            });
        }
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#popup').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var title= $('#title').val();
      var content=  $('#content').val();
      popup.show(title, content);
      return false;
  });
  
  $('.close-popup').on('click', popup.hide);
});
```

```css
.popup-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
}

.popup-description {
    font-size: 17px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 15px;
}

.popup-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ff0066;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    top: 25% !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.popup-title {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: .9em;
    padding: 5px 0px 0 10px;
    line-height: 1em;
    text-align: left;
}

.close-popup {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #ff0066;
}

    .close-popup:after {
        content: 'X';
        position: absolute;
        vertical-align: middle;
        top: 1px;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 1em;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Type text to show title" />
<input type="text" id="content" placeholder="Type text to show title" />
<input type="button" id="popup" value="open popup" />
<div class="popup-container">
    <div class="popup-wrapper">
        <div class="popup-title"></div>
        <div class="popup-description"></div>
        <div class="close-popup" tabindex="0" alt="Close popup" title="Close popup" aria-label="Close popup"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Good luck,
Ido.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Sorry, i'm not really good with javasript/jquery. But i manage to create the popup with your way. Few questions, which one is the part where the content of popup appear when the correct/incorrect answer chosen? And one more thing, how do I get to the next question, do i just add the button(next question) that i used before? Because i use toggle tab like the snippets i post above. Thank you.

Comment: update: the popup is great, thanks to you. One thing i have not able to solve is how to make the content react to which answer is chosen.

Comment: I'm sorry it's took little time to answer.   
You can pass full responsive html as string or even load html into the popup,so build and html template which hold the questions and answers, inject call the popup by passing the template.
in the template define elements by ID's so the next step you should write the events for each click (for instance the user choose answer number two - will get id="answer_2" etc, then click on the submit button- id="question_submit"- you should write the event that call to the popup again with the next question on same template)
I hope you understand the logic.